# Consider the element $2 + \sqrt{-5}$ of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a+b\sqrt{-5}\}$. Who are the associates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, solution-verification

Just to see if I got it right.

$\Bbb Z [ \sqrt{-5}]$ has only 1 and -1 as a unit as seen here:

[units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164039/units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt-5)

I konow that. Let $a, b \in D$, $a$ and $b$ are said to be associated if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$. But as the only units are $1$ and $-1$, then there is no $ \neq b$ such that $a = ub$, as seen here:

[Prove that $2$, $3$, $1+ \sqrt{-5}$, and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109552/prove-that-2-3-1-sqrt-5-and-1-sqrt-5-are-irreducible-in-math)

So $2 +  \sqrt{ -5} $ has no associates.

Comment: What about $-2-\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @Bcpicao Ooh that's true, i missed this one. But that's the only, rigtht?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the right idea, but you have omitted a lot of details. Let me fill them in.

Let $a$ be an associate of $2 + \sqrt{-5}$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Then we find that there exist $b,c\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $(2 + \sqrt{-5})b = a$ and $ac = 2 + \sqrt{-5}$. Combining these equations and rearranging, we find that
$$
(2 + \sqrt{-5})(bc - 1) = 0.
$$

Now, $2 + \sqrt{-5}$ is not a zero divisor in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, so that we must have $bc = 1.$ Thus, $b$ and $c$ are units, so that $b,c\in\{1,-1\}.$ If $bc = 1,$ we must have $b = c,$ so that the only associates of $2 + \sqrt{-5}$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are $\pm(2 + \sqrt{-5}).$